# How to detect remote disconnection in ASyncSocket

Tags: macos, cocoa, sockets, networking, asyncsocket

I am using ASyncSocket on Cocoa, however when the remote host disconnects I don't get the onSocketDidDisconnect event (maybe once every 5 tests). The -isConnected method returns me TRUE.
How can I detect a remote host disconnection ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

AsyncSocket will not report disconnections by the remote peer if there is no read enqueued. It's a bug I think in CFStream itself (don't quote me on this). By having a read always enqueued we seem to get along fine.

Answer (score 0):

How I implemented this is by all clients registering themselves every x seconds or minutes.
If a client disconnects, no registration anymore so I consider it as not connected.